# Why does UITableView Header (and only header) shift down 60 pts

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

I had an issue that drove me crazy and it turned out to be a bizarre solution so I thought I'd post in hopes that it helps someone else

I had a table view where I was manually showing the refresh control and offsetting the tableview. But for some reason, I was seeing instances of the first section header be shoved down 60 pts (and the tableview itself was as well, but not until you scrolled around). I tried offsets and insets and frames and bounds of the table view, with no luck. Turns out if you try set the refreshControl.attributedTitle it does this. I removed that line and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the attributedTitle of your tableview's refreshControl and you should stop seeing the vertical shift